# Linq query with group by clause

Tags: linq

My table has following columns:-

LevelId, LevelName, ScenarioId, TeamId.

I want to select LevelName corresponding to minimum LevelId when grouped by teamId

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. Please read the [guide to asking a good question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) and show [what you have tried](http://whatyouhavetried.com).

Comment: I have tried following query:-

Comment: @user2044161: Please update your original question with what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you want to:

- Group by team ID
- Within each group, order by level ID
- Take the first result's level name

So that sounds like:

```
var query = table.GroupBy(x => x.TeamId)
                 .Select(g => g.OrderBy(x => x.LevelId).First().Name);
```

Don't just take this query and include it in your code though - make sure you *understand* it so you can come up with your own solution next time you have something similar to do.

If this is in LINQ to Objects, you may find that [MoreLINQ](http://morelinq.googlecode.com) would be useful, with its `MinBy` method:

```
var query = table.GroupBy(x => x.TeamId)
                 .Select(g => g.MinBy(x => x.LevelId).Name);
```

This avoids ordering the whole group, just to find the entry with the minimum level ID.

Comment: I have tried :-

UnitOfWork.Levels.Entities.Where(
                        s => s.Scenario_Id == 10.GroupBy
                        (t => t.Team_Id).Select(
                            g => g.Min(t => t.Level_Id)).Distinct().ToList();

In above query i want to find levelName corresponding selected levelIds

Comment: @user2044161: It's *very* hard to read code written in comments, and the code you've posted doesn't even make sense (`10.GroupBy` ?) I've answered the question you asked - have you tried my solution, after understanding it?